# Extract Content of Powerpoint files in Readable Format?

Tags: windows, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2007

I'm trying to extract information from Powerpoint files in a readable format. By "readable" I mean removing the "slides" factor and flowing more like a word document, preserving images and basic formatting such as bolding, italics, bullets, etc.

I have no idea how to proceed. Is this something that only a VB script can achieve? Does such a script already exist to anyone's knowledge?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I can help with the readable part, not the formatting:
Upload the PowerPoint file into Google Docs, select it, from the "More..." dropdown select "Download..." and then "Plain text". You'll get the textual content in a .txt file.

Both PP and Docs allow you to save to PDF, if all you need is a formatted, yet widely readable format.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on conversion to plain text. I'd like to do something similar, that is removing the "slides" factor so that it flows more like a document. However, I need to preserve images and basic formatting (bold, italics, lists, etc.)